# While sorting: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to remove all duplicate and null elements of an array, then sorting it.

```
    cities = [js.city for js in company_jscollects]
    filter(None, cities)
    cities_unique = list(sorted(set(cities)))
```

But then I got this error:

Django Version:     2.0.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Exception Location:     D:..\views.py in dashboard_analytics, line 175

Line 175 being the one including the sorted function.

I am pretty confused because the error tells that there are None elements being compared to Strings, but I used filter to avoid that in the first place.

Comment: `filter` does not modify the list, you probably want `cities = filter(None, cities)`  though in this case you might as well just change the line above to `cities = [js.city for js in company_jscollects if js.city]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `filter(None, cities)` is not doing anything, since `filter(..)` itself does *not* filter the list, it creates an iterable with the filtered elements.

You can use:

```
cities = [js.city for js in company_jscollects]
cities_unique = list(sorted(set(filter(None, cities))))
```

Or probably more elegant:

```
cities_unique = sorted({js.city for js in company_jscollects if js.city})
```

since `sorted(..)` always returns a list, the extra `list(..)` will only result in more work to construct a list.